# Problemas com criação de campos not null com FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou com um problema na criação dos campos utilizando FluentNhibernate e Postgres.
**Classe Usuario:**

```
public class Usuario {
    public virtual int idUsuario { get; set; }
    public virtual string nome { get; set; }
    [NotNullNotEmpty]
    public virtual string login { get; set; }
    [NotNullNotEmpty]
    public virtual bool ativo { get; set; }
    [NotNullNotEmpty]
    public virtual string senha { get; set; }
}
```

**UsuarioMap:**

```
public UsuarioMap() {
    Table("usuario");
    Id(x => x.idUsuario).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id_usuario");
    Map(x => x.nome).Column("nome").Length(50);
    Map(x => x.login).Column("login").Not.Nullable().Length(30);
    Map(x => x.ativo).Column("ativo").Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.senha).Column("senha").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
}
```

Se a tabela não existe, ele cria normalmente todos os campos, com tamanho correto e validação not null:

```
CREATE TABLE public.usuario
(
    id_usuario integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('usuario_id_usuario_seq'::regclass),
    nome character varying(50),
    login character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    ativo boolean NOT NULL,
    senha character varying(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT usuario_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario)
)
```

Porém se a tabela existe e adiciono um campo na classe map, ele apenas cria o campo sem as validações:

```
**Class Usuario**
[NotNullNotEmpty]
public virtual string teste { get; set; }
```

.

```
**Class UsuarioMap**
Map(x => x.teste).Column("teste").Length(60).Not.Nullable();
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE public.usuario
(
    id_usuario integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('usuario_id_usuario_seq'::regclass),
    nome character varying(50),
    login character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    ativo boolean NOT NULL,
    senha character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    teste character varying(60),
    CONSTRAINT usuario_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario)
)
```

Se alguém já passou por isso e puder me ajudar, agradeço porque já estou dois dias pesquisando e não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou configurar o valor padrão para esse campo e passar um valor, porque, ao criar um novo campo em uma tabela existente se não for passado nenhum valor ele tem que ser `null`, por padrão. Logo isso ele colocará as regras e validações apropriadas para esse campo.

```
Map(x => x.teste).Column("teste").Default("teste").Length(60).Not.Nullable();
```

***Referente:*** [SOen - Specifiying Default Value for Datetime property in FluenNhibernate mapping class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22454182/6797930)

Comment: Opa, falha básica de lógica criar um campo notnull com valor nulo não vai mesmo.[

Comment: Não entendi?...

Comment: Só não consigo colocar caracteres como defaut, apenas numeros dessa forma:

    Map(x => x.teste).Column("teste").Length(10).Default("12345").Not.Nullable();

Desde já muito obrigado pela ajuda, acho que eu ia demorar um bom tempo para descobrir esse erro

Comment: @ElieltonBitencourt coloca qualquer tipo de caracter essa afirmação sua está estranha, porque eu fiz o teste com a palavra "teste" e funcionou de primeira!, estranho